# Can uglifyJS or terser obscure string literals in javascript code?

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs

One purpose of uglifyJS is making code difficult to understand. But users can search for the words in page to gain some logic of application code. So I want to ask if there is a way to make literals difficult to find.

I've checked the official docs and couldn't find any useful info.

```js
const noPermissionHint = "Sorry, you have no permission to view this page.";
```

The out code should not be too easy to locate by "Sorry" or "permission".

Comment: create a property file for all your messages and use the same in your code, that will also help in localization.

Comment: I would be concerned if your security depends on obscurity of javascript tbh! Uglify is deprecated so better to use terser. Your whole bundle would have to be decrypted on load and just as easy to see in Chrome inspector anyway

Comment: Or you could use this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-uglify

Comment: @AZ_ Thanks for your advice. Some apps don't need localization and string literals are easy to maintain.

Comment: @Dominic You are absolutely right. App security should not depends on obscurity of code. But I want to make the code hard to debug. If there is an option, I think many devs won't mind to turn it on.

Comment: @FabianTjoeAOn I seems to me string-uglify only obscure specific strings. What I need is that a tool/plugin automatically obscure all string literals for me.